# Working with classes in PHP

Tags: php, class

Let's say I have got the following class:

```
class Test
{
    function __construct()
    {
        // initialize some variable

        $this->run();
    }

    function run()
    {
        // do some stuff

        $this->handle();
    }

    function handle()
    {
    }
}
```

Normally I would create an instance like:

```
$test = new Test();
```

However I don't really need the `$test` anywhere since the functions in the class do all the work once and after that I won't need the instance of the class anymore.

What should I do in this situation or should I just do: `$test = new Test();`

I hope it makes sense what I'm trying to say if not please tell me.

Answer (score 9):

They should probably be static functions, if they don't require an instantiated instance:

```
class Test
{
    private static $var1;
    private static $var2;

    // Constructor is not used to call `run()`, 
    // though you may need it for other purposes if this class
    // has non-static methods and properties.

    // If all properties are used and discarded, they can be
    // created with an init() function
    private static function init() {
        self::$var1 = 'val1';
        self::$var2 = 'val2';
    }

    // And destroyed with a destroy() function


    // Make sure run() is a public method
    public static function run()
    {
        // Initialize
        self::init();

        // access properties
        echo self::$var1;

        // handle() is called statically
        self::handle();

        // If all done, eliminate the variables
        self::$var1 = NULL;
        self::$var2 = NULL;
    }

    // handle() may be a private method.
    private static function handle()
    {
    }
}

// called without a constructor:
Test::run();
```

Comment: I thought so too. However where / how should I initilize the variable which now takes place in the constructor. (PS the variables should be accessible by the other functions in the class)

Comment: @PeeHaa see additions above.  Static properties are initialized in an `init()` method, and set to NULL after calling `handle()`. Could also remove them inside `handle()`

Comment: great! thanks. Why do you eliminate the variables after finish?

Comment: @PeeHaa since the vars are static, they're shared by all instances of class `Test` and may hang around in memory for the script execution. If you won't do this more than once on a page, don't worry about destroying them.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't need it, just do:

```
new Test();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just call it like this `(new Test()).functionHere()`. Alternativly you could just make the function static and do `Test::functionHere()`

Comment: `(new Test()).functionHere()` never seen this style before. What is it called so I can look it up in the docs.

Comment: I don't know if it has an official name but you are basically creating the object without referencing it. As `new Test()` returns a new Test object which is imidatly ready for use. So by wrapping it in `()` you can imidatly use the object's methods

Answer (score 1):

None of those is required. Even if you keep the $test variable that won't change anything because it won't take even a 0,001% of the RAM memory. Just continue the program's flow. The best answer from the above is to initiate the class without saving an instance in a variable. Bet even if you do that won't change anything. If I were you, I was going to leave that variable, because later I if I add another function which needs to be called manually that would be the easiest way to call it.

Comment: /@Itehnological something more damn you name is too long: It's not really the performance / RAM I worried about. Just wanted to know what would be best practise in this case. Thanks for yor answer though :)

Answer (score 1):

Assigning a value is not required, it will work as

```
new Test;
```

Alternativly, you can write your class in static format:

```
class Test
{
  public static function run()
  {
    // do some stuff
    self::handle();
  }

  public static function handle()
  {
  }
}
```

And call your class as:

```
Test::run();
```